# Do we use static notifications or dynamic notifications for getting usernames and avatars from the server?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, watchos-2

I have read a ton on designing static/dynamic notifications. Everyone says use dynamic for more personalized data and try to stick with static since WatchOS often falls back to static anyway on low battery etc.

What I'm not clear about is if I can use a static notification for the same category "New Message" but each time changing the senders' names in the body to match the user object from the server.

- You have a new message from Karen
- You have a new message from Dave
- You have a new message from Jessica
- You have a new message from Tom

Also their avatar. Can each notification use a different user avatar from the server? With JSON payload we can get any data and populate any WatchKit ImageView / UILable even with a Static Notification?

[image]

In case I need to use a dynamic notification I have already created a subclass of `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController` for the dynamic notification controller with this method for testing dictionaries.

How would I populate the WK objects with the usernames/avatars?

```
override func didReceiveRemoteNotification(remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject], withCompletion completionHandler: ((WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void)) {

    NSLog("remoteNotification Dictionary %@",remoteNotification);
    completionHandler(.Custom) // same as completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType.Custom)



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to be dynamic from my point of view.Let say we got the payload data like that :

```
{
     "img_url" : "exmaple.com/ssd.jpg",
     "sender" : "Kelvin",
     "type" : "(your type name)"
}
```

**You can control your type with "New-Message" or "Video-Call" or "Reply".When you parse type,check it and show the user on UI.**

If you are going to parse the payload data from server,what you will parse is the following key "imgu_url,sender,type" every time the notification arrive and you will get the data from them,right?Most notifications go with that.I mean static.So,what important to do is setting the common key name for your requirement.There is no need to be dynamic.

Try read this : [Wat is the difference between static notification and dynamic notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381491/wat-is-the-difference-between-static-notification-and-dynamic-notification?rq=1)

What you should do is get the data and update the UI

**APNS FORMAT AND BACKEND GUIDE :**

Here what you should send exactly like that to iOS devices.If you don't set the payload like this format that was set by apple,you wont receive any notifications to your iDevices.

[APNS Payload Data Format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html)

And there is no need to create multiple apns file,try read their documentation on their server side script.Learn how they sent notifications to specific iOS devices : [One Signal](https://documentation.onesignal.com) or you can learn from [Parse](https://www.parse.com) too which become open-source now.

I am not a backend developer.So,I can't help you with that.Like I said,you can send the payload data base on what your application needs.

Comment: It's base on the requirement that you gonna do.There is no commonly used keys for chat type servers.You can set the key anything you like base on the requirement on your application.

Comment: Every APNS message have title,body,alert and additional data.So,there is no need to create multiple apns file.Control with additional data with the key and dynamic value base on the user action send by server.

Comment: You're right sorry. I will ask a new question. If you answer my new question I can mark it as correct as well :) Thank you so much for your great answers. I will delete some of my posts above to clean it up. Please delete any unnecessary posts.

Comment: You welcome... ;),please give me link,if u want me to help.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36124820/the-anatomy-of-getting-chat-server-data-from-ios-to-watchos